# Data Recovery on external Hard Drive using Recuva

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery

Have an external 1TB portable hard drive which had contents of around 5000 photos stored on it. One day plugged it in to find nothing there.

Apologies in advance for knowing nothing about data recovery.

First, ran a normal scan using Recuva, found nothing
Second, ran a deep scan which took about two hours and found around 1000 images with names like img985.jpg and so on(so approx 4000 missing). These I restored to a new HDD.

There were also a number of files with unusual names (ie, not image file names or image types) which the status showed as unrecoverable.

There was one very large file which showed the status as "Excellent"; however upon trying to recover it to a new HDD, a warning came up saying the file size was 50,985,403,357 GB (which is obviously not true because it is well over the 1TB limit of the disk). So I skipped recovering that file.

I did not copy anything back to the original disk, so as not to cause any overwrite issues.

Which leads to three questions:
1 Are there any further steps that can be taken to recover the other 4000 missing image files?
2 Is there any way of compressing the very large file so as to be able to restore it?
3 This event having spurred my curiosity about data recovery, can anyone recommend concise beginner resource material to learn about it?